# Error when I'm trying to access project

Tags: php, laravel

When I'm trying to get access to my project I have errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in H:\xampp\htdocs\schedule.dev\bootstrap\app.php:14 Stack trace: #0 H:\xampp\htdocs\schedule.dev\public\index.php(36): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in H:\xampp\htdocs\schedule.dev\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
```

How can I solve it?
I've read similar question:
[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724231/illuminate-foundation-application-not-found-in-bootstrap-app-php14)
but I don't know how install php-xml in windows.

Comment: have you `composer install`ed?

Comment: you needed to install php dom extension. after installing that with `sudo apt-get install php-xml` ... I followed the steps of installing Laravel 5.3 again and everything worked (ubantu). you can google about different OS for installing PHP dom extension.